# C++ Struct initialisation problem

Tags: c++

This c++ code is working fine , however memory validator says that I am using a deleted pointer in: 
grf->filePath = fname; Do you have any idea why ? Thank you.

Dirloader.h

```
  // Other code  
  class CDirLoader  
    {
    public:    
     struct TKnownGRF
     {
      std::string filePath;
      DWORD encodingType;
      DWORD userDataLen;
      char *userData;
     };
       // Other Code

     CDirLoader();
     virtual ~CDirLoader();
```

Dirloader.cpp

```
// Other code
void CDirLoader::AddGroupFile(const std::string& _fname)
{
// Other code including std::string fname = _fname;
TKnownGRF *grf = new TKnownGRF;
grf->filePath = fname;
delete grf; // Just for testing purposes
```

P.S.: This is only an code extract. Of course if I define a struct TKnownGRF inside .cpp and use it as an actual object, gfr.filepath = something, instead of pointer grf->filepath=something, than it is ok, but I do need to have it inside *.h in CDirLoader class, due to many other vector allocations.

Comment: can you please raise the curtain a little more?

Comment: You pass in _fname and assign fname to filePath. Is that a typo or the real code ?

Comment: Yes there is much more code like: std::string fname = _fname; LoCase(fname); - fname part should be fine. The problem is grf -> filepath

Comment: What is `fname`? There's no declaration for `fname` in your code.

Comment: looks like classic memory leak, what happens to `grf` after end of `CDirLoader::AddGroupFile`?

Comment: I have tested it with a sample string instead of fname and it is fine. Even the original code is working but memory validator marked it red.

Comment: For erjot - grfs.push_back(grf);

Comment: And memory check went OK. Validator is complaining about use of deleted pointer.

Comment: Should be grf->filePath initialized somehow ?

Comment: assuming you're deleting each element of `grfs` only at `CDirLoader::~CDirLoader` code you've posted looks ok and the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: The problem isn't in the code you've posted. Can you cut your code down to a small, compilable example that exhibits the problem?

Comment: Does newing into grf correctly setup the filePath variable?  What does the TKnownGRF class/struct look like?

Comment: @Michael Dorgan: it's in first snippet ...

Comment: grfs is defined in *.h  - std::vector<TKnownGRF*> grfs;

Comment: For Mike, the project is too large and it isn't only my code so I am afraid I can't compile and send it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the function returns `void`

```
void CDirLoader::AddGroupFile(const std::string& _fname)
```

the question is what are you going to do with `grf`?

Are you going to `delete` it? If so, then, why do a `new`? you can just declare a `TKnownGRF` variable on the stack! In that case, `_fname` is not contributing to the logic of this method.

I guess that the class `CDirLoader` has a member variable of type `TKnownGRF`, say `grf_`, and that need to be used in the `AddsGroupFile()` method, e.g.:

```
grf_.filepath = _fname;
```

Comment: There is std::vector<TKnownGRF*> grfs; in  Dirloader.h   Quote" the question is what are you going to do with grf? Are you going to delete it?" No, I am using grfs.push_back(grf); at the end of void CDirLoader::AddGroupFile  CDirLoader deosnt have a member of TKnownGRF except grfs vectors and a few others.  Also if I define another TKnowGRF struct inside my *.cpp I could use gfr.filepath insdead of gfr->filepath. That solves the problem with validator, but how do I push_back that into a globally used vector of an original  TKnowGRF *.

Comment: For everybody's benefit, please update the question with these additional and valuable details. Globals are bad, but if you have no choice, then you have to use `grfs`, and it seems `grfs.push_back( grf );` is valid. There must be some code to de-allocate `grfs` (e.g. `grfs.clear()`) though.

Comment: Quote " If so, then, why do a new?" Without new I will get warning: arning C4700: local variable 'grf' used without having been initialized

Comment: Ad > de-allocate grfs  Thank you for an idea however I just tried to comment  grfs.push_back( grf ); and put there simple delete grf; just for testing purposes and validator still reports an critical error in grf->filePath

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen to be using an older version of STL, say, VC6, and running multithreaded? Older versions of STL's string class used a reference counted copy on write implementation, which didn't really work in a multithreaded environment. [See this KB article on VC 6](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813810).

Or, it's also possible that you are looking at the wrong problem. If you call `std::string::c_str()` and cache the result at all, the cached result would probably be invalidated when you modified the original `string`. There are a few cases where you can get away with that, but it's very much implementation specific.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. However we are using VC 7.1 and multithreaded should be fine there. (Hopefully :-))

Comment: The second idea I am not sure but I do not see there any problematic parts. Could you be please more specific ? Additional string related code is: 1 std::string fname = _fname;    2 LoCase(fname);  3  FILE *f = fopen(fname.c_str(), "rb");